# Detect WordPress REST API response?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

What is the best way of detecting whether a WordPress response was generated by the REST API? There don't yet appear to be any conditional tags like `is_feed()` or `is_page()`?

Some hooks late in the WordPress lifecycle may alter output, such as naively appending html tags or debugging content. The problem is, if the response is a JSON blob from the REST API, appending content will invalidate the JSON response.

The [`is_feed` conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Syndication) doesn't recognize REST API responses as feeds and returns `false`.

Answer (score 6):

The `rest_api_loaded` method in [wp-includes/rest-api.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1326d9e2c7edb05fbd8462a56c44b9a51d50e2df/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L253) defines a `REST_REQUEST` constant, that's helpfully labeled "Whether this is a REST Request". That constant then gets checked in [class-wp-query.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/af885f45cf0f16e2c8c609786991c0fe2c148af5/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L960). Here's a simple little `is_rest` conditional function based on that check:

```php
function is_rest() {
    return ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST );
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, that will always return false if called before `parse_request` action